# Datetime Picker in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using this datetime picker :- 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker
Official document link :- https://cuppalabs.github.io/angular2-datetimepicker/#/datetimepicker.

Now, I have successfully implement it. It's perfectly working but time picker is not showing. 
As per their document I have set timepicker:false as well as timepicker:true.

In component.ts file.

```
date: Date = new Date();
settings = {
    bigBanner: true,
    format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a',
    defaultOpen: true
}
```

In component.html file.

```
 <angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="settings"></angular2-date-picker>
```

Screen Shot.

[image]

**Edit :-** 
I think the problem is that setting object is not working from .ts file because if I remove the setting object then also it's only showing date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure out the problem some how setting object is not working from .ts file. 
So, I have changed it like

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="date" [settings]="{
        bigBanner: true,
        timePicker: true,
        format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a'
    }"></angular2-date-picker>
```

And it's working.

**Note :-** I have tried 4-5 datetime pickers in Angular-5 and this is the only datetime picker which is working. So we can use it.

Comment: I am trying to implement this datetime picker in a form, but every time I got to set the time, it submits the form. What's the best way around this?

Comment: @jmckie. I think the problem is with your handling event because If you use ngModel then page won't get refresh or submit the form.

Comment: @Bhavin how can I set min date?

Answer (score 6):

This will work as an object from the .ts file. Notice that your HTML file contains a line that your .ts file is missing. The "timePicker: true" line is absent in your .ts settings. So your final settings object in that .ts file should look like this:

```
settings = {
    bigBanner: true,
    format: 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm a',
    defaultOpen: true,
    timePicker: true
}
```

As an aside, disabling the bigBanner option with "bigBanner: false" automatically disables the timePicker in this tool. I notice that your's is enabled, but thought it was worth mentioning if others find this solution looking for other reasons that their timePicker is not displaying.